# Fedora 30 gets stuck at Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service

Tags: fedora, boot

After updating to Fedora 30 and reboot, the Maschine fell in a login LOOP, but after some reboots it gets stuck at something Like this:
[OK] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service
Within a black background. And i don't know what to do now.

Could you help me with some ideas ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In the GRUB boot menu, edit the boot settings, find the line that loads your actual kernel (it starts with the word `linux`) and remove the options `quiet rhgb` to get a more verbose boot display. That might give you more clues about what the system is trying to do *after* it starts the Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service, since that might be the failing component.

Try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> when the boot process is getting stuck - it might give you a rescue shell. Failing that, you might have to add the boot option `systemd.unit=emergency.target` to the `linux` configuration line of GRUB, or boot to rescue mode from an installation media.

It seems that updates to Fedora 30 have sometimes encountered a particular bug in the update process. Please check if this bug report is relevant to your situation:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1705651

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after installing Debian in Hyper-V.

Installation was fine with GUI. I selected GNOME as desktop and after the installation was complete and the first reboot was executed, the boot process stuck.

There was something with `Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service` and two lines below then `GNOME Display Manager`.

In a second installation I selected XCFE (or Cinnamon) desktop instead of GNOME and the boot was successful.
Maybe the problem with fedora is similar.